# Mercurial.NET do not clone a specified file from repository

Tags: azure, mercurial, bitbucket, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Worker Role application which can clone from Bitbucket/Mercurial repositories.
After a successfull authentication I started to clone from the repository via SSH.

```
var repository = new Mercurial.Repository(<LOCALRESOURCEPATH>);

repository.Clone(repoUrl.ToString(), new Mercurial.CloneCommand().WithObserver(new Mercurial.DebugObserver()).WithUpdate(false).WithTimeout(100000));
```

I choose a very big number for the Timeout, because the size of the repository is minimum about 100-150 MB (it contains an Orchard source).

The code works fine, the Mercurial.NET starts to clone the content of the repository to the disc.

Than at one point (as you can see in the picture that visual c++ 2008 file) the transaction aborted.

But why? What can be the problem with this file?

[image]

Comment: Might it be related to 255 characters file path limitation? Try to relocate the repository, for example to C:\my_rep\.

Comment: Yes, it's related to the limitation. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should post the conclusion as an answer and then accept it to give it more visibility. Or let @Teddy do it and accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to 255 characters file path limitation. Try to relocate the repository, for example to the folder C:\my_rep.